# Angularjs -> how to initialise variables in angular-style

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to re-write an application using angular.js, but I still do not see how it works (more or less).

For instance. In my previous code, I had a function that was executed once everything was loaded that initialised variables, accessed for everyone in a window.variable style.

Now I want the same here.

My idea was to build a factory to return an object with all the variables, and then make that everyone had access to this object (somehow).

The questions are:
1- Am I right? I should initialise variables through a factory?
2- And how can I "call" this factory-method at the beginning of the code? with the module.run function?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably put the variables in a service, and then inject that into a wrapping angular controller. Any other controllers that you would want to have access to these 'global' variables would be nested under the wrapping controller, thus inheriting the variables.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.service("globVars", function () {
  var vars = {};
  vars.someVar = "a";
  vars.someOtherVar = "b";
  return vars;
});

app.controller("WrappingCtrl", function ($scope, globVars) {
  $scope.globVars = globVars;
});

app.controller("NestedCtrl", function ($scope) {
  console.log($scope.globVars.someVar); // => "a"
});


<html ng-app="app">
  <div id="wrapper" ng-controller="WrappingCtrl">
    <div class="nested" ng-controller="NestedCtrl">
      {{globVars.someVar}}
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was thinking and it works (using a factory instead of a service though). Thanks a lot!

Comment: wrapping controller is not a good idea... instead I would rather inject the service only in the places where you need to use the variables... not every part of your application necessarily need to know about those variables

Comment: That doesn't sound bad at all. Would it be too much if I ask for some simple example code of how to inject the service??

Comment: *You mean like in the WrappingCtrl, put there the service in any controller that I need. I'll work on it :)

Comment: I agree with you Doodec, partially. In some cases, it surely would be  a better idea to inject the variable service into the controllers that actually are to use it. Another scenario might be that you have a set of variables for a particular part of your view layer. In this case, It'd make sense to use an inherited set of variables from a wrapping controller. If, all of the nested controllers are to have access to it. Otherwise, you're not looking for global (or in this case, wrapped) variables.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should avoid using global variables as much as you could

But if you have to use them, you are right, you can initialize them in `module.run` and add the module in the app dependencies

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access some variables, you must see to $rootScope, because you can access $rootScope everywhere.

Also you must use angular config and run functions.

I advice to you don't use global scope, because it affects on app speed, memory leaks etc.